# GDB: Getting parameter values when they have no name?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm debugging an app with GDB and when I step into a frame, I see something like this:

```
#2  0x00007fff4da4276b in MHWRender::THgeometryOverrideEvaluator::doDGBoundingBox(TdgContext const&, OGSMayaCompoundNode*) ()
```

Normally, I'd just print out parameter addresses, but in the case of the second parameter here, there's no parameter name. How do I get the info I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the info I need?

The output you got is indicative of the code being compiled without debug info.

The easiest fix is to add `-g` as appropriate and rebuild your application.

Without debug info, you can only do debugging at assembly level, which requires knowing the calling convention on your platform (which you did not specify).

Assuming this is Linux on `x86_64`, and assuming that `doDGBoundingBox` is not a `static` function, the first (`this`) parameter will be passed in `$rdi`, second (the `TdgContext&`) in `$rsi`, and third (the `OGSMayaCompoundNode*`) in `$rdx`. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).